# Query to fetch details from Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I need to fetch the list of persons from an array(Ex: `String[] getPersons`) as input. I can't figure out how to compare and fetch data from Cosmos DB using a LINQ expression. I experimented with `GetItemLinqQueryable`, but I don't know if it's the right way to use it.

```cs
var db = Client.GetDatabase(databaseId);

var container = db.GetContainer(containerId);

var q = container.GetItemLinqQueryable<Person>();

var iterator = q.Where(p => p.Name == getPersons[0]).ToFeedIterator();

var results = await iterator.ReadNextAsync();
```

If I am using the above one, I could only able to get only the first person result but I need to get the other persons in the array as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Contains. It is equivalent to [ARRAY_CONTAINS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-array-contains) in Cosmos DB Array functions.

You can try this code:

```
var iterator = q.Where(p => getPersons.Contains(p.Name)).ToFeedIterator();
```